Build a Singularity container until writing to SIF?
When creating a Singularity Image File (.sif) from a Singularity script, the sif can get too big for services such as GitHub Actions, which causes a Continuous integration script to break.
However, before creating that sif file, Singularity is doing useful things too. If one cannot create the final sif file, would it be possible to let Singularity stop just before that phase? In that way, a Singularity script can be verified to work, without killing a CI script due to lack of space.
How to let Singularity build a container until writing to SIF?
I've searched the manual and documentation. I especially looked for a --dry-run flag, but could not find it. Does it exist?
